# Struggling with password generator in Javascript. Won't correctly change text on page

Tags: javascript

So this code is supposed to generate a random password... pretty much just a bunch of random characters. It seems to work other than the fact that the password doesn't show up correctly in the HTML afterwards.

The code is supposed to ask how many characters do you want and then whether or not you want uppercase letters and numbers. All the steps are logged in the console so I know its generating correctly.

```js
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
var characters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var upperChars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
  "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
];

var characterNum = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
  "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
];

var upperNum = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
  "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
  "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
];
// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);



function generatePassword() {
  var charLength = prompt("How many characters do you want in your new password?");
  var whichCase = confirm("Do you want uppercase letters?");
  var num = confirm("Do you want numbers in your password?");

  console.log(charLength);
  console.log(whichCase);
  console.log(num);

  // if uppercase and numbers are confirmed
  if (num === true && whichCase === true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < charLength; i++) {

      charPick = upperNum[Math.floor(Math.random() * upperNum.length)];
      console.log(charPick);
      password = password.toString() + charPick.toString();
      console.log(password);



    }
  }
  //if uppercase but no numbers
  else if (num != true && whichCase === true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < charLength; i++) {

      charPick = upperChars[Math.floor(Math.random() * upperChars.length)];
      console.log(charPick);
      password = password.toString() + charPick.toString();
      console.log(password);



    }
  }
  // numbers no uppercase
  else if (num === true && whichCase != true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < charLength; i++) {

      charPick = characterNum[Math.floor(Math.random() * characterNum.length)];
      console.log(charPick);
      password = password.toString() + charPick.toString();
      console.log(password);
    }

  } else if (num != true && whichCase != true) {
    for (var i = 0; i < charLength; i++) {

      charPick = characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)];
      console.log(charPick);
      password = password.toString() + charPick.toString();
      console.log(password);


    }
  }
  return password;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Password Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <textarea readonly id="password" placeholder="Your Secure Password" aria-label="Generated Password"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using password in the function without defining it. It is getting some DOM object for the value of password, the element with id password, but if you define a local variable with let for password at the beginning of the generate password function it all works fine.

```js
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
var characters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
var upperChars = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                      "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

var characterNum = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                    "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

var upperNum = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value= password
  }

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);



function generatePassword(){
  var charLength = prompt("How many characters do you want in your new password?");
  var whichCase = confirm("Do you want uppercase letters?");
  var num = confirm("Do you want numbers in your password?");
  
  // This creates a local variable for the password instead of getting the DOM object with id="password"
  let password = '';

  console.log(charLength);
  console.log(whichCase);
  console.log(num);

  // if uppercase and numbers are confirmed
  if(num === true && whichCase === true){
    for(var i = 0; i <charLength; i++){

      charPick = upperNum[Math.floor(Math.random()*upperNum.length)];
      console.log(charPick);
      password = password.toString()+charPick.toString();
      console.log(password);



    }
  }  
//if uppercase but no numbers
    else if(num != true && whichCase === true){
      for(var i = 0; i <charLength; i++){

      charPick = upperChars[Math.floor(Math.random()*upperChars.length)];
      console.log(charPick);
      password = password.toString()+charPick.toString();
      console.log(password);



    }
  }
// numbers no uppercase
    else if(num === true && whichCase != true){
      for(var i = 0; i <charLength; i++){

        charPick = characterNum[Math.floor(Math.random()*characterNum.length)];
        console.log(charPick);
        password = password.toString()+charPick.toString();
        console.log(password);       
      }

    }
    else if(num != true && whichCase != true){
      for(var i = 0; i <charLength; i++){

        charPick = characters[Math.floor(Math.random()*characters.length)];
        console.log(charPick);
        password = password.toString()+charPick.toString();
        console.log(password);


  } 
    }
    return password;
}
```

```html
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
<input type="text" id="password">
```